# LIBGDX - How to get rid of banding effect on gradient background?

Tags: libgdx, gradient

I am having banding issues with gradient related textures in my game and I can't seem to find what's the cause and how to solve it.

Here's what I am talking about: On the left is a gradient in my game, whereas on the right is a gradient generated in a gradient generator application(Tint). We can clearly see banding issues.

[image]
[image]

To create my gradient, I used this code to generate a Texture used to create an Image that I scale to fill the user's screen.

```
Pixmap pix = new Pixmap(2, 2, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
pix.setColor(colorSchemes[backgroundColorScheme.ordinal()].getTopColor());
pix.fillRectangle(0,0,2,1);
pix.setColor(colorSchemes[backgroundColorScheme.ordinal()].getBottomColor());
pix.fillRectangle(0,1,2,1);

Texture texture = new Texture(pix);
texture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, 
Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
pix.dispose();
```

I also have another issue with banding when I try to add [fog-like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMlq8.png) actors on top of the background to animate it a bit. I scale them, change their opacity and move them around and again I get banding issues as highlighted in the picture below.

[image]

I am trying to replicate a background effect like in this game
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_vBczzj3NAU

I have this code in my render screen render loop:

```
@Override
public void render (float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
    Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
}
```

Any ideas on how I can solve those issues? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the number of bits per color channel (I believe the default is 5 bits) to 8 bits fixed the banding problem for me.

In AndroidLauncher.java

```
AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
config.r = config.g = config.b = config.a = 8;
```

In DesktopLauncher.java

```
LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
config.r = config.g = config.b = config.a = 8;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I already tried that and it didn't change anything. I don't know if it's overwritten somewhere else because even setting them to 1 bit doesn't change anything.
I noticed in the AndroidGraphics.java class, there is a bufferFormat initialized with private BufferFormat bufferFormat = new BufferFormat(5, 6, 5, 0, 16, 0, 0, false);
Could that be the issue?

Comment: I'm not sure what else the problem could me, sorry. You could also try asking on the official LibGDX forum, they might be able to help. https://www.badlogicgames.com/forum